# Echo files in a directory case-insensitively?

Tags: bash

Currently, in my bash script I print out a list of all the files in a directory. The thing is, all the files starting with a capital are printed first, then the lower case. How can I combine to make one alphabetized list? This is a list of more or less system files that I cannot rename to all be the same case.

EDIT: I need to run an if on each file so that's why I use the loop. I can't just display them all.

example:

```
for file in *.txt
do
    if grep -Fxq "$file" disabled.dat
  then
     echo -e "$GREEN${file}$NC"
  else
     echo "${file}"
  fi
done
```

outputs:

```
Apple.txt
Banana.txt
Pear.txt
aardvark.txt
snake.txt
zebra.txt
```

I'm new to bash so all help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Change the collation order used by your operating system.

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C bash -c 'echo *.txt'
Apple.txt Banana.txt Pear.txt aardvark.txt snake.txt zebra.txt
$ LC_COLLATE=en_US bash -c 'echo *.txt'
aardvark.txt Apple.txt Banana.txt Pear.txt snake.txt zebra.txt
```

Comment: How would I use this in my loop? For each file I run an if statement to figure out if that file name is in a .dat file I have. If so, change the color of it. This seems to print everything out all at once

Comment: You would set the collation before running the script, either as part of the system configuration or by using `env` in the shebang.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have very much experience and have not been able to find how to set it using env. When I type LC_COLLATE=en_US in either terminal or my script it gives me a warning saying that there is no such file or directory.

Comment: Then you are mistyping it, or not using a Bourne-compatible shell. `LC_COLLATE` is a variable name and you should be able to assign it, just like you can assign a new value e.g. to `PATH`.

Comment: @tripleee: it's probably `en_US` that's missing. If you set LC_COLLATE to a string which doesn't correspond to a locale, bash will produce a warning like: `bash: warning: setlocale: LC_COLLATE: cannot change locale (qq_QQQ): No such file or directory`

Comment: But then the error message is different. I would speculate illegal spaces around the equals sign.

Comment: @tripleee: The exact error message is in my comment. OP said "a warning saying that there is no such file or directory". Illegal spaces would produce `LC_COLLATE: command not found`.

Comment: Yes, I am typing it in right. This is probably because I am using my iPhone. I'm not sure if any of you would know how to install it from an iPhone.  Where can I download it? And generally where are those files located?

Comment: And yep I ran 'locale' in terminal and all I have is the default c. So where can I download en_US?

Comment: @user2338197: That's an excellent question. I suggest you ask it on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ where it is possible someone might know how to get locale files onto an iPhone.

Comment: Thank you guys for the info! I have posted a question on apple.stackexchange.com. Wish me luck!